# MOD_Rewrite for the directory

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, routes

I'm trying to get MOD_rewrite on .htaccess to rewrite rule so that if someone types domain.com/presentations to be same as domain.com/cakephp directory

I've got below so far but the problem is cakephp is not recognising it as a root. In routes.php I've got `Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'contents', 'action' => 'conf'));` so that it triggers contents controller and action conf when you type cakephp directory root in URL of browser.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
    Redirect /presentations /cakephp
</IfModule>
```

Is there a way to achieve this so that we can get this result from root .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule presentations /cakephp [L]
```